# Inner Join Two Table, aggregating varchar fields

Tags: oracle, concatenation

Sorry I change my question a bit .
I have two table and I want to merge them

```
  TERMS_TABLE

 ID  | TERMS
 309 | 'hardware'
 309 | 'software'

TFIDF_TABLE

  ID | TERMS
 309 |'computer,phone,mp3....'
```

Now I want to add TERMS column of `TERMS_TABLE` to terms column of `TFIDF_TABLE` like that

result should be:

```
NEW_TFIDF_TABLE

  ID | TERMS
 309 |'computer,phone,mp3....,hardware,software'
```

I try this code:

```
Insert into    NEW_TFIDF_TABLE
SELECT T.ID, T.TERMS ||', '|| TT.TERMS FROM TFIDF_TABLE T
INNER JOIN TERMS_TABLE TT  ON  T.ID=TT.ID
```

but it does not do what I want
How can I do that  ?

Modification: I forgot an issue. If TFIDF_TABLE already contains  TERMS of TERMS_TABLE
 then I should not insert this term to the NEW_TFIDF_TABLE. To do this control mechanism what should I do ?

Example :

TERMS_TABLE

```
 ID  | TERMS
 309 | 'hardware'
 309 | 'software'
 309 | 'computer'



TFIDF_TABLE

  ID | TERMS
 309 |'computer,phone,mp3....'
```

RESULT:

NEW_TFIDF_TABLE

```
  ID | TERMS
 309 |'computer,phone,mp3....,hardware,software'
```

Comment: what the result your getting for this? coz it seems to be correct

Comment: I getting the result:                                      NEW_TFIDF_TABLE                                                   ID | TERMS                                                       309 'computer,phone,mp3....,hardware'                               309 |'computer,phone,mp3....,software'

Comment: @shanmugamgsn As you can see, he's trying to aggregate the terms.

Comment: @Golez Trol : yes he trying to concat two strings. i guess | symbol wont work out.

Answer (score 4):

If you got Oracle 11g, you can use the LISTAGG function, like so:

```
Insert into    NEW_TFIDF_TABLE
SELECT T.ID, T.TERMS ||', '|| LISTAGG(TT.TERMS, ',') 
FROM TFIDF_TABLE T
INNER JOIN TERMS_TABLE TT  ON  T.ID=TT.ID
GROUP BY t.ID, t.TERMS /* assuming the id is unique in t */
```

If you're on an earlier version, you can create your own aggregate functions using a package. I've build this FNC_CONCATCOMMASEPARATED function, which I freqently use myself.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "AT_CONCATCOMMASEPARATED" as object
(
  V_CONCAT varchar2(32767), -- concatenated strings

  static function ODCIAggregateInitialize(
    P_CONTEXT in out AT_CONCATCOMMASEPARATED)
  return number,

  member function ODCIAggregateIterate(
    self  in out AT_CONCATCOMMASEPARATED,
    P_VALUE in     varchar2)
  return number,

  member function ODCIAggregateTerminate(
    self     in  AT_CONCATCOMMASEPARATED,
    P_RESULT out varchar2,
    P_FLAGS  in  number)
  return number,

  member function ODCIAggregateMerge(
    self      in out AT_CONCATCOMMASEPARATED,
    P_CONTEXT in     AT_CONCATCOMMASEPARATED)
  return number
);

create or replace type body AT_CONCATCOMMASEPARATED is

static function ODCIAggregateInitialize(
  P_CONTEXT in out AT_CONCATCOMMASEPARATED)
return number
is
begin
  if P_CONTEXT is null then
    P_CONTEXT := AT_CONCATCOMMASEPARATED('');
  else
    P_CONTEXT.V_CONCAT := null;
  end if;

  return ODCIConst.Success;
end;

member function ODCIAggregateIterate(
  self    in out AT_CONCATCOMMASEPARATED,
  P_VALUE in     varchar2)
return number
is
begin
  if self.V_CONCAT is null then
    self.V_CONCAT := P_VALUE;
  else
    self.V_CONCAT := self.V_CONCAT || ', ' || P_VALUE;
  end if;

  return ODCIConst.Success;
end;

member function ODCIAggregateTerminate(
  self     in  AT_CONCATCOMMASEPARATED,
  P_RESULT out varchar2,
  P_FLAGS  in  number)
return number
is
begin
  P_RESULT := substr(self.V_CONCAT, 0, 4000);

  return ODCIConst.Success;
end;

member function ODCIAggregateMerge(
  self      in out AT_CONCATCOMMASEPARATED,
  P_CONTEXT in     AT_CONCATCOMMASEPARATED)
return number
is
begin
  if P_CONTEXT.V_CONCAT is not null then
    if self.V_CONCAT is null then
      self.V_CONCAT := P_CONTEXT.V_CONCAT;
    else
      self.V_CONCAT := self.V_CONCAT || ', ' || P_CONTEXT.V_CONCAT;
    end if;
  end if;

  return ODCIConst.Success;
end;

end;

create or replace function FNC_CONCATCOMMASEPARATED (input varchar2) return varchar2
aggregate using AT_CONCATCOMMASEPARATED;
```

The insert statement then becomes:

```
Insert into    NEW_TFIDF_TABLE
SELECT T.ID, T.TERMS ||', '|| FNC_CONCATCOMMASEPARATED(TT.TERMS) 
FROM TFIDF_TABLE T
INNER JOIN TERMS_TABLE TT  ON  T.ID=TT.ID
GROUP BY t.ID, t.TERMS /* assuming the id is unique in t */
```

Comment: Note that there is a max length (I believe 4000 characters) that this function can concat.

Comment: For example It contains two records for ID 309

Comment: Oops. Alias mixup. I meant t (TFIDF_TABLE). If they're also not unique in that table, you may need a more complex join, because you will need to aggregate over both table. If the id is unique in TFIDF_TABLE, this 'simple' aggregation will work fine.

Comment: I want to modify my question . Should I edit it or post another question

Comment: That depends. Some additional information can be added to the question, but if in retrospective the question appears to be wrong, you might better ask a new question and maybe refer to this one, explaining why you needed to ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

use (works with Oracle 9i and up):

```
INSERT INTO NEW_TFIDF_TABLE (ID, TERMS)
SELECT DISTINCT 
TT.ID, 
T.TERMS || ',' || XMLAGG (XMLELEMENT (C, TT.TERMS) ORDER BY TT.TERMS ASC).EXTRACT ('//text()') , ',') AS TERMS
FROM TFIDF_TABLE T
INNER JOIN TERMS_TABLE TT ON T.ID=TT.ID
```