# Need help to debug the code

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Can any body please help I am getting below error for the code.

ORA-06550: line 20, column 33:

PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to '||'

ORA-06550: line 20, column 12:

PL/SQL: Statement ignored

...condition1: if I put value explicitly in my parametrize cursor then it is not reaching till 2nd FOR loop. and after printing 'Inside' statement is executed.
Condition2. If I put variable as parameter then it is giving above mentioned error.

```
    DECLARE 
/* First cursor */
    CURSOR get_tables IS
     SELECT DISTINCT * FROM src_table_list tbl ;
/* Second cursor  */
    CURSOR get_columns(v_table_name varchar2) IS 
     SELECT SUBSTR (SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH (column_name, ','), 2) csv 
      FROM (SELECT column_name , ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY column_name ) rn,
               COUNT (*) OVER () cnt
          FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS where table_name = v_table_name)
     WHERE rn = cnt
    -- and col.sn = v_sn
  START WITH rn = 1
  CONNECT BY rn = PRIOR rn + 1;

BEGIN 
 FOR i IN get_tables LOOP
dbms_output.put_line( 'Inside ' );
    FOR j IN get_columns(i.table_name) LOOP
       dbms_output.put_line('SELECT '|| j ||'FROM'||i.table_name||' ;' );
       dbms_output.put_line( ' ' );
    END LOOP;
 END LOOP;
END; 
/
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to concat `j` in the output, but j is a reference to the row in the cursor. This is a type that cannot be implicitly cast to a string, so that concat fails.

You probably meant to write

```
dbms_output.put_line('SELECT '|| j.csv || ' FROM ' || i.table_name || ';');
```

PS. what do you do with that connect by? Is it to get comma separated values? Maybe you can use [LISTAGG, or my custom variant of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885619/inner-join-two-table-aggregating-varchar-fields/7885793#7885793).

Comment: Probably the 2nd query is wrong. Have you tried it by itself, passing a fixed table name? There's no syntax error anymore, but I can't tell for sure what you want it to return. See question + suggestion in the last line of my answer.

Comment: The symptoms are clear, so please read carefully: *The line is not ignored, but the second cursor just doesn't return any rows.* Just try to write it as a query, which makes testing and debugging much easier. After that, you can put it back in this procedure.