# Oracle Select Query - Select columns based on column start text

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle10g

I have a table which has got a field which has many "Item numbers" (starting from 8%, 2%, etc...). These Item numbers have further components, which are also stored in the very same column (because each component is also an Item). Now the requirement is to if I encounter an Item number that has its component number starting from 8%, then I need to create a new column against the Main Item number (some thing which is called 800-Level Items) and store it there, and if the main Item Number has 2% component number then i should put it into yet another column something like (200-Level).

```
                     Field1  XLike YLike
                     ---------------------
 (Main Item)            XXXX       
 (Main Item's component)YYYY
 (Main Item's component)ZZZZ
 (Main Item's component)XABC
 (Main Item's component)YABC
```

Now depending upon the starting character of the Sting in Field1, I need to segregate the values in fields XLike and YLike in following manner:

```
Field1   | XLike    | YLike
-------------------------
XXXX     | XABC     |      
YYYY     |          | YABC
ZZZZ     |          |
XABC     |          |
YABC     |          |
```

Comment: The Edition is Oracle 10G

Comment: I'm sorry it's really unclear what you want to do. Your first table has lots of rows and three columns, your second has a single row with all the data. That looks like a big modeling problem. Could you explain what's you're trying to do functionally, and what/how you'd like to use the data? (What sort of queries?)

Comment: Hi, I have a table which has got a field which has many "Item numbers" (starting from 8%, 2%, etc...). These Item numbers have further components, which are also stored in the very same column (because each component is also an Item). Now the requirement is to if I encounter an Item number that has its component number starting from 8%, then I need to create a new column against the Main Item number (some thing which is called 800-Level Items) and store it there, and if the main Item Number has2% component number then i should put it into yet another column something like (200-Level).

Answer (score 0):

for 10g you can try

```
select 
  wm_concat(case when field1 like '%X%' then field1 end)  XLike,
  wm_concat(case when field1 like '%Y%' then field1 end)  YLike
from table1
```

11g has listagg function

```
select listagg(case when field1 like '%X%' then field1 end, ';') within group(order by field1) XLike,
listagg(case when field1 like '%Y%' then field1 end, ';') within group(order by field1) YLike
from table1
```

Comment: If wm_concat doesn't work, check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7885793/511529

Comment: @Dmitry..Thank-you for your post..But it gives error......misplaced from statement!

Comment: first query? please, could you provide full error text?

Comment: Error in second Query the one using Listagg unction

Comment: Error in second Query the one using Listagg function: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: but second query is for 11g, please try first one

Comment: Hi, It is still showing the same error when I try to use the first Query, ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"
*Cause:    
*Action:.....Kindly let me know your Email Id and maybe I'll Send you the Query which is generating the errors

Comment: The Error using Query2 is :ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long
01489. 00000 -  "result of string concatenation is too long"
*Cause:    String concatenation result is more than the maximum size.
*Action:   Make sure that the result is less than the maximum size.